# django how to load view for each user separatly?

Tags: python, django

I have a login page that users can login, but all users can view the same data or each other data! I would like to separate each users data like facebook, for example, that each user loads his/her own data.

can any one give a clue how to implement it!

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can get user-specific info if they are logged in by looking at `request` in your view. How can you get it there? Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/ How do you use it? check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#users (and all over that page, generally)

Comment: Are you saying you want to hide information from the profile, unless, the two people are "friends"? Or you simply want to create a profile page which displays specific information about the user but is public for anyone to see?